# Detecting periodic components in discrete-time signals

Tags: discrete-signals, periodic

I am looking for real data examples where it is of interest to detect the presence of a periodic component of some discrete-time signal when the period of the periodic component is not known.

Suppose that $\{X_t:t\in\mathbb Z\}$ is a discrete-time signal (univariate or possibly multivariate) and consider the situation where this signal can be modeled as $$X_t=s_t+\varepsilon_t$$ for each $t\in\mathbb Z$, where $\{s_t:t\in\mathbb Z\}$ is a deterministic periodic component such that $s_t=s_{t+p}$ for all $t\in\mathbb Z$ and $\sum_{t=1}^ps_t=0$ with some period $p\ge2$ while $\{\varepsilon_t:t\in\mathbb Z\}$ is some stationary random noise sequence. We observe $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and we want to detect the presence of the deterministic periodic component $\{s_t:t\in\mathbb Z\}$, i.e. we want to know whether $X_t=\varepsilon_t$ for $t\in\mathbb Z$ or $X_t=s_t+\varepsilon_t$ for $t\in\mathbb Z$ with some period $p\ge2$.

In many situations, we expect the presence of certain periodic components and hence it is not reasonable to assume that $p$ is unknown. For example, if we record temperature, then it is clear that we should expect to see daily and yearly periodic components. It does not make a lot of sense to check, say, for a three day periodic component. In many situations, some theory suggests that there should be some periodic components present and then it makes sense to try to detect these particular periodic components instead of assuming that the period is unknown.

However, I suspect that there are examples (maybe in engineering or astronomy) where it is not clear whether the periodic component should be present and what period of the periodic component we should expect to detect.

> I am looking for real data examples (preferably multivariate but univariate examples are also of interest) where it is not clear whether the periodic component should be present and where it is not clear what period we should expect to detect. References to textbooks, papers or websites are very welcome.

I have no background in signal processing and my question or phrasing might seem strange. Please let me know if I should clarify some parts of my question.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The phrasing seems fine, the question is surprising / not overly sensible: Anything can be useful in signal processing, and detection of periodicities is practically the same as spectral estimation, and has myriads of applications and algorithms. Does that actually answer your question? Could you maybe add a bit of explanation how you come to this question?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am playing around with some statistical methodologies that detect periodicities in multivariate discrete-time signals (or multivariate time series). We observe $\{x_t:t\in\mathbb Z\}$ and we want to know if there any periodic components present in the signal. I am looking for examples of situations where such questions are of interest so that I could test different methodologies and see how they work. I hope this makes my question a bit clearer. Would you have any particular data examples in mind?

Comment: ah, so you're actually asking for methods to detect periodicities to compare to your own?

Comment: @MarcusMüller That would be of interest as well but this would probably make the question too broad. Essentially, I am looking for a concrete real-world data example in signal processing of a situation where we observe some multivariate signal and we want to know if that signal has any periodic component. Maybe you would have a reference to a chapter in some textbook or a paper where such questions are investigated. As I mentioned, I do not have background in signal processing.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb: can you explain a little more about why "multi variant" is relevant here. Do you want to detect periodicity across time in each vector, across vectors at each time instance or are you looking for some sort of 2 dimensional periodicity?

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb quite the opposite is true: Asking for what you actually need makes more sense and is less overly broad than asking us to pick from the whole world of DSP something that does something similar to what you want to compare. Again, finding periodic signals is something that we do in DSP all the time, it's really hard for me to pinpoint how to help you. I've got an institute library with *shelves* on spectral estimation, and all these books would fit the description of "detecting presence of periodic components"

Comment: So, really, in an attempt to narrow this down, could you **edit** your question to describe your actual need rather than asking vaguely for examples, please?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I edited my question and included more details. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: hm, yeah, this *is* the spectral estimation problem, yes. You're asking for the presence of an unknown periodic signal. This happens in thousand and one place, really. I could write something about detection probabilities in Q-tone multicarrier systems, about pulse-position modulation, about at least four kinds of radar, about hearbeat detection in search and rescue, about pulsar observations, about… Again, shelves of books on spectral estimation in libraries. Could you maybe tell us a  bit about your actual your field or background? Are you a particle physicist, a geologist, an astronomer, a

Comment: chemist, a microbiologist, an expert in cognitive vision? Maybe we can find something to help you based on your field. If you can not give us any background on why you're asking this: I'm sorry, this is still too broad. Also, could you elaborate where the multi-variance comes into play here?

Comment: @MarcusMüller My field is statistics. We have a methodology that detects periodic components in multivariate discrete-time signals when the period is unknown. In many situations, it seems that some theory suggests whether the periodic component should be present and what the period of should be. It seems that in many situations trying to detect a periodic signal of any length isn't of particular interest. I'm trying to find a real data example where it actually is of interest. Examples that you mentioned are very interesting. I'll try to read more about them. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Ah! Statistics! OK, then Steven Kay's *Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing: Detection theory* is possibly a book you've seen! I like it. What might be relevant to your problem might also be *Detection of Signals in Noise* by McDonough; I don't know whether that is well-available, though. From statistics' origin, communications theory takes a few cool parametric estimators. I can only *imagine* you might like the MUSIC algorithm (in its spectral, not its Direction-of-Arrival version); also, try ROOT-MUSIC.